# Using bigint datetimes to select records older than X days

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, bigint

I have dates stored as bigint in my table, and I'm trying to select records older than 30 days.  I have seen a ton of questions on SO and Google related to this question, but I'm not finding what I need.

Heres what I have, which seems very inefficient:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  alert
WHERE 
  ('1969-12-31 19:00:00 GMT'::timestamp + (alert.mytstamp::text)::interval) < (localtimestamp - INTERVAL '30 days')
```

From what I understand, it is converting the bigint `mytstamp` field to a timestamp in order to compare it to the "30 days ago" timestamp.  It does this for every record in the table :(.  It seems more efficient to convert the current time stamp - 30 days to a bigint ONE TIME, then compare that to all my bigint dates.

My SQL skills are weak, so go easy :).  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again I found a solution right after posting to SO.  Its a good luck charm I guess.  Anyway, this seems to be what I'm looking for, and is much more efficient:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  alert
WHERE 
  alert.timestamp < extract('epoch' from (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  - INTERVAL '10 days'))::bigint
```

I'm wondering if postgres does the calculation for `extract('epoch' from (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  - INTERVAL '10 days'))::bigint` once, or for every record comparison though.

Comment: Both CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and the calculation are deterministic; PostgreSQL should calculate it once. (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is the server's time at the start of the current transaction.) [Other time functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) may behave differently.